# xamarin collectionview and listview draw speed very slow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My test phone is LG-V50 and LG-G6 and Note5

my test collectionview code

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ViewList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedView}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Frame Grid.Row="0" WidthRequest="500" CornerRadius="8" BackgroundColor="#FFEAEAEA" HorizontalOptions='FillAndExpand' Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid Margin="-15,-10,-15,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  >
                                <Label x:Name="test" Text="{Binding DeviceName}" Style="{StaticResource DiviceTitel01}" FontSize="30" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button Image="close.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.ViewListDeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource ExitBtnStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>


                            <customControls:Board Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{Binding VM}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>



                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="-10,0,-10,0">
                            <Button Text="button1" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="140" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.InfoPageClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource InfoBtnStyle}" />
                            <Button Text="button1" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.DetailDataClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource DetailviewBtnStyle}"/>
                            <Button Text="button2" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.RefPageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource MoveBtnStyle}" TextColor="black"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

and listview test code

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ViewList}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedView}"                  
      HasUnevenRows="True" 
      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"                  
      >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <customControls:ExtendedViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="#FF8FB5C3" >
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid Margin="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Frame Grid.Row="0" WidthRequest="500" CornerRadius="8" BackgroundColor="#FFEAEAEA" HorizontalOptions='FillAndExpand' Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Grid Margin="-15,-10,-15,0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  >                                                    
                                        <Label x:Name="test" Text="{Binding DeviceName}" Style="{StaticResource DiviceTitel01}" FontSize="30" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Button Image="close.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.ViewListDeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource ExitBtnStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <customControls:Board Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{Binding VM}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="-10,0,-10,0">
                                    <Button Text="buuton1" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="140" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.InfoPageClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource InfoBtnStyle}" />
                                    <Button Text="button2" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.DetailDataClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource DetailviewBtnStyle}"/>
                                    <Button Text="button3" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BoardName}, Path=BindingContext.RefPageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference test},Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource MoveBtnStyle}" TextColor="black"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </customControls:ExtendedViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and

my customcontrol code

```
<Grid IsVisible="{Binding Model.IsWlevelControlVisible}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding Model.Color0}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="-2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="W0" Text="{Binding Model.Title_0}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"  FontSize="24" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Model.AIValue_0}" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Font="23"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Model.Value_0, Converter={StaticResource StingFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference F0}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="23" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,-40,0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Model.Value_0, Converter={StaticResource UnitConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference F0}}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="22" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="-2">

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Model.Time}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

and Customcontrol Data communication is updated every 2 seconds

It is slow to draw an item except for data communication and without binding.
Excluding controls in collection view and list view makes drawing items fast, but adding controls makes drawing items very slow.

Can you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: How many items did the listview load ? Could you try to put all the controls into ListView.ItemTemplate directly(not using custom control) to see if problem persists ?

Comment: The maximum number of lists is 5.

I can't exclude controls.

Comment: Check the suggestions for improving listview performance :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#listview-performance-suggestions

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news... but welcome to Xamarin.Forms... a dying technology... people are moving to Fluttter now